# Error Removing Row from Gtk TreeStore

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I have a function for removing an individually selected row from a liststore, but every time I call it, I get an error that reads:

```
Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_list_store_remove: assertion `iter_is_valid (iter, list_store)' failed
```

Here is the function:

```
void delete_row()
{

    selector = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview));
    gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(selector, &model, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_remove(GTK_LIST_STORE(store), &iter);

}
```

The selection mode is set to single. I use the same model and iterator in different functions without any issue.

Am I going about this in the right way? I based my code on the following tutorial:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GTK%2B_By_Example/Tree_View/Events

** Edit **

NOTE: I have also tried using `gtk_list_store_remove(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter);` which gives the same error.

Declarations (global scope from header):

```
GtkTreeView *treeview;
GtkTreeModel *model;
GtkTreeIter iter;
GtkListStore *store;
GtkTreeSelection *selector;
GtkMenuItem *delete_row_item;
```

Initialize tree related structures:

```
//Load tree and list related structures.
treeview = GTK_TREE_VIEW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "treeview"));
selector = GTK_TREE_SELECTION(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "treeview-selection"));
store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_builder_get_object(builder,"liststore"));
//Set the tree model
model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(treeview);
```

Get the delete menu item from the glade file and connect it to the function:

```
delete_row_item = gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "delete");
g_signal_connect(delete_row_item, "activate", G_CALLBACK(delete_row), NULL);
```

Comment: I don't see the problem here - please show more code, e.g. how the `delete_row()` function is called, how the variables are declared etc.

Comment: @ace I edited my post to include more information.

Comment: I don't really know... Now that I think of it, try `gtk_list_store_remove(GTK_LIST_STORE(model), &iter)`. I don't know whether it will work though.

Comment: @ace Yeah, I tried that earlier and got the same error. I'll edit my post to include that.

Comment: Try printing the return value of `gtk_tree_selection_get_selected()`, see if it is true or false.

Comment: Returning false means that there is no node selected. Are you sure you clicked on a row (or selected a row programmatically) before calling the function?

Comment: @ace Yes, I clicked on a row and it appeared to be selected. I have no problem editing individual cells (I have the cell renderers linked to a different function that is called on the edited signal) but for some reason I'm having this issue with removing rows.

Comment: Well then I can't see anything wrong. Perhaps you can show us a minimal compilable example that demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not have anything to do with it, but I think it's worthwhile mentioning it:

*You are playing with fire! Global variables are dangerous, particularly in an environment which works with events, such as gtk.*

It's quite possible that the parameters you store in the global variables are changed by another event. Particularly dangerous is `iter` which is very probably prone to used in several places. You should really use local variables in your function (in each function separately):

```
void delete_row()
{
    GtkTreeView *treeview;
    GtkTreeModel *model;
    GtkTreeIter iter;

    treeview = GTK_TREE_VIEW(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "treeview"));
    selector = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(treeview);
    gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(selector, &model, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_remove(GTK_LIST_STORE(store), &iter);

}
```

Also, note that you have defined a liststore, and a model which probably cause confusion:

```
 GtkTreeModel *model;
 GtkListStore *store;
```

Both are pointing to a model (liststore is just a special case of model)
Don't mix both - be aware!

*In fact I just noticed that you are actually using store and model mixed in the delete function:*

> gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(selector, &**model**, &iter);
>   gtk_list_store_remove(GTK_LIST_STORE(**store**), &iter);

Comment: Thank you very much for bringing this to my attention! Using local variables in the function fixed the issue. Now, I just have to go through my program and change everything else so there won't be other issues in the future.